How to combine outputs of different events in golang for func HandleRPC from "google.golang.org/grpc/stats" package
// HandleRPC implements per-RPC tracing and stats instrumentation.
func (c *statsHandler) HandleRPC(ctx context.Context, rs stats.RPCStats) {
 switch rs := rs.(type) {

  case *stats.InHeader:

     if rs.Client {
        fmt.Printf(rs.Header)
    }

  case *stats.End:
    ign := false
    c.lock.RLock()
    ign = c.ignore
    c.lock.RUnlock()

    if !ign {
        duration := rs.EndTime.Sub(rs.BeginTime)

        var st string
        s, ok := status.FromError(rs.Error)
        if ok {
            st = s.Code().String()
        }

        c.results <- &callResult{rs.Error, st, duration, rs.EndTime}

        if c.hasLog {
            c.log.Debugw("Received RPC Stats",
                "statsID", c.id, "code", st, "error", rs.Error,
                "duration", duration, "stats", rs)
        }
    }
}

}

I have the response metadata coming on event *stats.InHeader and the rest of grpc stats on event *stats.End, I want to combine metadata and grpc stats into one struct object callResult at the end of the grpc call. I am quite not sure how to realize this, I am really new to go and grpc. Could someone please help me with this, Thank you!

Interesting. I was unfamiliar with stats before your question. I suspect an implicit question is how to associate data from the disparate events within each RPC? You could update the context in your TagConn and TagRPC methods with a unique identifier to associate them. If you want to persist this data beyond the lifetime of each Handler, you'll want to pass your persistence mechanism into the Handler when you create it.

@DazWilkin But I don't receive *stats.InHeader event where I can access response metadata inside of TagConn or TagRPC methods

As your code shows (!?), you receive the requests headers in your HandleRPC method when you receive *stats.InHeader type. The response headers (if any), would be accessible when you receive *stats.OutHeader type (for which you don't have a switch branch). The Handler (all its methods) carry context.Context and you can add key:value pairs to it to represent the handler's. its connections' and each connection's RPCs' state.

@DazWilkin as said in your first comment and after referring to this link https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/5823#issuecomment-1349707446 I was able to solve this

type MutableObject struct {
    InMetadata metadata.MD // Example mutable field
}

// TagRPC implements per-RPC context management.
func (c *statsHandler) TagRPC(ctx context.Context, info *stats.RPCTagInfo) context.Context {

    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "InHeader", &MutableObject{})

    return ctx
}

// HandleRPC implements per-RPC tracing and stats instrumentation.
func (c *statsHandler) HandleRPC(ctx context.Context, rs stats.RPCStats) {
    switch rs := rs.(type) {

    case *stats.InHeader:
        var headerValue metadata.MD
        
        if rs.Client {
            ign := false
            c.lock.RLock()
            ign = c.ignore
            c.lock.RUnlock()
            if !ign {
                headerValue = rs.Header

                if header, ok := ctx.Value("InHeader").(*MutableObject); ok {
                    header.InMetadata = headerValue
                }
            }
        }

    case *stats.End:

        ign := false
        c.lock.RLock()
        ign = c.ignore
        c.lock.RUnlock()

        if !ign {
            duration := rs.EndTime.Sub(rs.BeginTime)

            var st string
            s, ok := status.FromError(rs.Error)
            if ok {
                st = s.Code().String()
            }

            // Retrieve the header value from the context

            
            var ts time.Time
            if header, ok := ctx.Value("InHeader").(*MutableObject); ok {
                databroker_timestamp, err := strconv.ParseInt(header.InMetadata["ts"][0], 10, 64)
                if err == nil {
                    ts = time.Unix(int64(math.Abs(float64(databroker_timestamp)/1000000000)), databroker_timestamp%1000000000)
                }

            }

            c.results <- &callResult{rs.Error, st, duration, rs.EndTime, ts, 10, 10}

            if c.hasLog {
                c.log.Debugw("Received RPC Stats",
                    "statsID", c.id, "code", st, "error", rs.Error,
                    "duration", duration, "stats", rs)
            }
        }
    }

}


Add a mutable object to the context in TagRPC
Modify the mutable object on *stats.InHeader event
Finally access the object on *stats.End

